# Increasing image size inside of WINE

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, wine

I have an application designed for Windows XP, that needs to be ported to a Mac running 10.9.2.  I found WineBottler and have created a package for the app, which works perfectly with the exception of image size.  I can make the Wine window bigger, but as is typical with Apple computers, the image inside of the window doesn't grow.  The fonts are nearly unreadable on the new 27" screen when they were previously optimized for 800x600 17", is there some way to scale the image using Wine or WineBottler?